Decompose a real matrix into rotation and real eigenvalues
I want to abstract away the rotation performed by a real matrix $A$, so that it can be written either as $A = B R$ or as $A= R B$, where $R$ is a rotation and $B$ has real eigenvalues, with the hope that $B$ can be interpreted, under a fixed change of coordinates, as combinations of just scaling and shearing.
The Jordan decomposition tells that any matrix $A$ (even complex, but I'm interested in real only) can be decomposed as $A = P^{-1} J P$, where $J$ is a matrix that lists the eigenvalues of $A$ on the diagonal (which can be complex), contains only ones or zeros in the super-diagonal, and is zero everywhere else. Ones in the super-diagonal are related to shears and complex eigenvalues are related to rotations, so that's why I wonder if it is possible to "take away" the rotations out of $A$ as $A=RB$, and claim that $B$ is free of rotations.

Try Polar decomposition

@user8675309 Indeed, the Polar decomposition solves the question. So, modulo rotations, all linear transformations are simply applying arbitrary scales on any linearly independent set of vectors. Shear is not especial in that regard.
